# How to check if value in list is not in another IList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, if-statement, logic

I want to be able to edit employee roles through a checkboxlist in MVC.

1. If they already have the role, don't do anything.
2. If they don't already have the role, add it.
3. If they already have the role, but it was deselected, remove it.

I can't figure out the logic for the third one. I have an IList of existing roles, and a List of the roles that were set as true.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRoles.Count(); i++)
        {
            var employeeRole = new EmployeeRole
            {
                EmployeeID = vm.EmployeeID,
                RoleID= Int32.Parse(postedRoleIds[i])
            };

            if (vm.ExistingRoles.Contains(selectedRoles[i]))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                db.EmployeeRoles.Add(employeeRole);
            }


        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the IF statement to check if I need to remove a role in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: vm is the ViewModel I am using that contains the IList of ExistingRoles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, the best way to go about doing this is to get two separate lists -

Roles to be added, roles to be deleted. So the logic should be something like,

```
   IList<Role> rolesToBeAdded = new List<Role>();
   IList<Role> rolesToBeDeleted = new List<Role>();

   foreach(Role role in existingRoles)
   {
       if(! selectedRoles.contains(role))
       rolesToBeDeleted.Add(role);
   }

   foreach(Role role in selectedRoles)
   {
       if(! existingRoles.contains(role))
       rolesToBeAdded.Add(role);
   }
```

After this, add roles from rolesToBeAdded and delete roles from rolesToBeDeleted.

If you are doing this in an enterprise level solution, you might want to avoid doing stuff right out of the viewmodel etc. You might want to extract the lists of existing and newly selected roles, pass them to a business logic dll which handles the business logic around it. Putting all of this in your controller and view logic is going to hurt you later when it comes to maintaining this.